# After activating environment wrong python is used despite `which python` showing correct one

Tags: python, conda

?!

```
(soundmap) seni@seni-thinkpad:~/git/soundmap$ python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Mar 24 2021, 16:29:44) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
(soundmap) seni@seni-thinkpad:~/git/soundmap$ which python
/home/seni/anaconda3/envs/soundmap/bin/python
(soundmap) seni@seni-thinkpad:~/git/soundmap$ /home/seni/anaconda3/envs/soundmap/bin/python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  4 2021, 15:09:15) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

The first entry in `$PATH` is the folder where the env's python is located.

More info:

```
(soundmap) seni@seni-thinkpad:~/git/soundmap$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/usr/local/bin/python3.8
(soundmap) seni@seni-thinkpad:~/git/soundmap$ /home/seni/anaconda3/envs/soundmap/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/home/seni/anaconda3/envs/soundmap/bin/python
```

PATH:

```
/home/seni/anaconda3/envs/soundmap/bin:/home/seni/anaconda3/condabin:/home/seni/.local/bin:/home/seni/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/seni/Android/Sdk/emulator:/home/seni/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/seni/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/seni/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/seni/Android/Sdk/emulator:/home/seni/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/seni/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/seni/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: it does not, added output to post

Answer (score -1):

If you are running this from a script, then you could have the shebang line pointing to the wrong version?

Search for the file or link to the one you want. And edit the top line of the script to have the path to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/python2
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: I'm clearly not running a or from a script.

Comment: @Nimitz14 sorry but there was nothing clear in your question